# Ubuntu Direct X issue

Tags: drivers, graphics

Im trying to play a game called Conquer Online. WHen I go to load the game i get an error that reads "Conquer online cannot be started. The problem could be from your version of Direct3D. It is suggested you re install your graphics driver". So how do I install my graphics driver again?

Comment: DirectX is a windows driver

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't, since DirectX is a Microsoft product. Microsoft doesn't provide support for Linux so there isn't a whole lot you can do about it. I am assuming you try to run this game via Wine. The only thing you can try look at the [Wine Application Database](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1729) for steps you might try from other people who tried to install this game under Linux.

Comment: Wine sucks. Every game I downloaded for Wine crashes after like 3 launches. I switched to Play On Linux which isnt much better. I will just switch to dual boot i guess.

Comment: If you're an active gamer, unfortunately that's the only real solution.. I do it too. I use Ubuntu for the serious stuff and a seperate Windows partition I installed and optimized just for gaming. Works like a charm. :)

Comment: How would i go about doing that?